# Perfect Squares Without Borders

Tags: code-golf, matrix

Given `n=m^2`, return a list of integers that do not border the `m x m` grid of integers from `1 to n`.

### Examples

#### n=1 (m=1)

Grid:

```
[1]
```

Return:

```
[]
```

#### n=4 (m=2)

Grid:

```
[1,2]
[3,4]
```

Return:

```
[]
```

#### n=9 (m=3)

Grid:

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]
```

Return:

```
[5]
```

#### n=16 (m=4)

Grid:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4]
[ 5, 6, 7, 8]
[ 9,10,11,12]
[13,14,15,16]
```

Return:

```
[6,7,10,11]
```

---

For higher values of `m`, [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154691/59376) answer does a great visualization.

---

Rules:

- You may take in either `m` or `n` (where `n = m*m`).

  - If taking in `n` you are allowed to have undefined behavior where there exists no `m` for `n` (E.G. 15).
  - `n > 0`, `m > 0`: Both must be integer values.
- The output may be as a 1D/2D array, matrix or whitespace delimited
- The output must be in order from least to greatest.

  - If outputting as a matrix this means it must be as it would be in the grid.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count wins.

Comment: Complete fault on my end, I read it incorrectly.

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper hey man, if I had a nickle for every time I did that I'd be able to buy a beer or two.

Comment: If outputting as a 2D array, can a single empty array be included in the result?

Answer (score 6):

## C, 50 bytes

```c
i;f(m){for(i=m;++i<m*m-m;)i%m>1&&printf("%d ",i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3NCsIwEITveYol0LJr7KFH2dZ3kUhkD1NLraeSZ48hinP75oeJwyPGUkwTQ4703NhmaAg24YQBKtbhOvb9utmyJ/bdnfzZRHOpTLjZwuIOR1V1TNzceVTCdFEKAdKyb6O16o/@aX3vL/b@52SXywc)

Answer (score 6):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 31 bytes

```octave
@(m)vec2mat(1:m*m,m--)(2:m,2:m)
```

Returns a matrix.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNXsyw12Sg3sUTD0CpXK1cnV1dXU8PIKlcHiDX/pynYKiTmFVtzcaXlFynkAnmGVoZGXApAkAbUypWal/IfAA)

Comment: Nice! I've never come across the `vec2mat` function before.

Answer (score 6):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 26 bytes

```matlab
@(m)find((t=[0:m-2 0])'*t)
```

The code defines an anonymous function that inputs `m` and outputs a (possibly empty) column vector.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI1czLTMvRUOjxDbawCpX10jBIFZTXatE83@ahqEmV5qGEYgwBhEmmv8B)

#### Explanation

```matlab
@(m)                          % Define anonymous function of m
          t=[0:m-2 0]         % Build row vector [0 1 2 ... m-2 0] and assign it
                              % to variable t
         (           )'       % Complex-conjugate transpose into a column vector
                       *t     % Matrix-multiply that column vector times the row
                              % vector t. This gives an m×m matrix with zeros in
                              % the border and nonzeros in the other entries.
    find(                )    % Linear indices of nonzero entries. The result is
                              % in increasing order
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
’Ṗ×+€ṖḊ€
```

A monadic link taking `m` and returning a list of lists (the inner rows).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw8yHO6cdnq79qGkNkPFwRxeQ8f//f0MDAA)**

#### How?

```
’Ṗ×+€ṖḊ€ - Link m                    e.g. 5
’        - decrement                      4
 Ṗ       - pop (implicit range of input)  [1,2,3]
  ×      - multiply by m                  [5,10,15]
     Ṗ   - pop m                          [1,2,3,4]
   +€    - add €ach                       [[6,7,8,9],[11,12,13,14],[16,17,18,19]]
      Ḋ€ - dequeue €ach                   [[7,8,9],[12,13,14],[17,18,19]]
```

Comment: Didn't feel like doing the python one ;)?

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 31 bytes

```hs
f m=[i|i<-[m..m*m-m],mod i m>1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00h1zY6sybTRjc6V08vVytXNzdWJzc/RSFTIdfOMPZ/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCmoLJfwA)

Math version:

```hs
f(m) = {i : i ∈ (m, m² - m), i mod m < 1}
```

:P

Comment: Wait, this isn't valid, `f(5)` should be `7,8,9,12,13,14,17,18,19`

Comment: Wait, oops I'm a dumbass.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>44</s> <s>43</s> 32 bytes

```r
function(n)(x=n:(n^2-n))[x%%n>1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPU6PCNs9KIy/OSDdPUzO6QlU1z84w9n@ahonmfwA)

Returns a vector.

Comment: Neat output format, is that by default how a matrix is output in R?

Comment: Yep, that's the `print` function for a `matrix`.

Comment: You can omit the second `m` in `matrix(1:m^2,m,m,T)`: `matrix(1:m^2,m,,T)`

Comment: @JAD yes, of course. Thanks.

Comment: Nice one, what do you think about using scan()? You might save 2 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8@2ODkxT0PTWqPCNs9KIy/OSDdPUzO6QlU1z84w9r/ZfwA "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## Pure Bash, 49

The boring answer:

```bash
for((i=$1;i++<$1*$1-$1;));{ ((i%$1>1))&&echo $i;}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##HYs7DoAgEAV7TrHFSkCDyRY2It7FD0YKIFE7wtkR7d5k5q3LfZYjXuDBBUjU90PWsEdmtzOCN@hHdtsHlAL0XyiEM0jadd2E1CKpClLqBFU0SDNJyfl/Rqdz@RbbY7DlBQ).

---

Or the interesting answer for 52:

```bash
(($1>2))&&eval echo \$[$1*{1..$[$1-2]}+{2..$[$1-1]}]
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifll@kkKuQmadQbainZ1prrZCSz5WanJGvkGurkmvFVZxaoqCrq6CS@19DQ8XQzkhTU00ttSwxRwGsJkYlWsVQC6QTxNA1iq3VrjaCcgxja2P/g1RxpeTnpf4HAA).

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
sÆ½ḊṖ$⁺€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//c8OGwr3huIrhuZYk4oG64oKs////MTY)

Comment: Using `m` one could do `²s⁸ḊṖ$⁺€` too. (I have also posted another `m` alternative method.)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Already discovered that, but no byte saving over there, you can't remove the `⁸` :(

Answer (score 3):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 28 bytes

```py
k=>filter(u=>1<u%k,k..k*~-k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@z/b1i4tM6cktUij1NbO0KZUNVsnW08vW6tON1vzf0FRZl6JRpqGiabmfwA)

Takes **m** as input.

#### How?

Filters the integers in **[k, k<sup>2</sup>-k)** that, when divided by **k**, yield a remainder higher than **1**. This ensures that both ends are trimmed, because the first one yields **0** and the last one yields **1**. It is also guaranteed to return a higher value for any valid integer, because they are consecutive.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 31 bytes

```
Table[# i+j+1,{i,#-2},{j,#-2}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PyQxKSc1WlkhUztL21CnOlNHWdeoVqc6C0zHqv0PKMrMK4lOi1aOjVXTdwhKzEtPjTaN/Q8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
LItä¦¨ε¦¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fx7Pk8JJDyw6tOLcVRP7/b2gGAA)

Comment: `LItä¦¨ε¦¨` is fine, the output can be a 2D array.

Comment: Oh, I should have read the spec better. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 35

```bash
seq $1 $[$1*$1-$1]|sed 1~$1d\;2~$1d
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##Fcs7DoAgEAXAnlO8YisTSNbERuJJ1EJlDRZAFDs/V8dYTTXzlH1Z04GALeJiY5rHwiUli08IHYVWZTmhNSiULDuIQT1xRayJxzuLA7/EbrD1T/mjcilK@QA).

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>23</strike> 19 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to FrownyFrog!

```
1 1}:@}.-@%:}:\1+i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DRUMa60cavV0HVStaq1iDLUz9f5rcilwpSZn5CukKZhAGOrqMAFLdAFDM3QRYzOu/wA)

My original olution:

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 23 bytes

```
[:|:@}:@}.^:2-@%:]\1+i.
```

Takes n as input, returns a matrix

### How it works

`1+i.` - generates a list 1..n

`-@%:` - finds the square root of n and negates it (m)

`]\` - makes a table (matrix) m x m from the list

`^:2` - do the following twice:

`|:@}:@}.` - drop the first row, then drop the last row, then transpose

`[:` - cap the fork

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o61qrBxqgUgvzspI10HVKjbGUDtT778mlwJXanJGvkKaggmEoa4OE7BEFzA0QxcxNuP6DwA)

Comment: `1}:@}.-@%:}.@}:\1+i.`

Comment: No, `1 1}:@}.-@%:}:\1+i.`

Comment: @FrownyFrog - Cool, thanks! I didn't know about the list left argument of `}.`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
lambda t:[k for k in range(t,~-t*t)if k%t>1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHEKjpbIS2/SCFbITNPoSgxLz1Vo0SnTrdEq0QzM00hW7XEzjD2f0FRZl6JQpqGieZ/AA)

I promise this is my last answer (to this challenge) today. Takes **m** as input.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 36 bytes

```julia
m->reshape(1:m*m,(m,m))[2:m-1,2:m-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59mm5Sanpn3P1fXrii1OCOxIFXD0CpXK1dHI1cnV1Mz2sgqV9dQB0zG/k/NS@FKyy9SyLU1tLJU4FIAgoKizLySnDyNXE0wNyWzuCAnsVIjDSigiaJAkwuo@z8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 32 bytes

```ruby
->m{(m..m*m-m).reject{|e|e%m<2}}
```

Takes `m`, returns a one-dimensional array.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y63WiNXTy9XK1c3V1OvKDUrNbmkuia1JlU118aotvZ/gUJatGEsF4gyglDGEMok9j8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
:G\1>&*f
```

Input is `m`. Output is the numbers in increasing order.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38o9xtBOTSvt/38TAA)

#### Explanation

Consider input `4` as an example.

```
:     % Implicit input: m. Push range [1 2 ... m-1 m]
      % STACK: [1 2 3 4]
G\    % Modulo m, element-wise
      % STACK: [1 2 3 0]
1>    % Greater than 1, element-wise.
      % STACK: [0 1 1 0]
&*    % Matrix of pair-wise products
      % STACK: [0 0 0 0;
                0 1 1 0;
                0 1 1 0;
                0 0 0 0]
f     % Column vector of linear indices of nonzeros. Implicit display
      % STACK: [ 6;
                 7;
                10;
                11]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 bytes

```apl
1+⊢⊥¨∘⍳2⍴0⌈-∘2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CYb/00Ck9qOuRY@6lh5a8ahjxqPezUaPercYPOrp0AVyjf7/LwEqqX7Uu/VR56IiIFMn7VHvLiv1tMTMHHUgCyhR9Ki7RT0/W72Wy7DkUe8aLiMwaVyiY8plUqJgpmCuYGigYGgIAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 bytes

```
²õ òU ÅkJ ®ÅkJ
```

Takes `m` as input

### Explanation

```
 ²õ òU ÅkJ ®ÅkJ                                      
                // U = input                         | 3
U²              // U squared                         | 9
  õ             // Range [1...U²]                    | [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    òU          // Cut into slices of U              | [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
       Å        // Remove the first item             | [[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
        kJ      // Remove the last item              | [[4,5,6]]
           ®    // Map:                              |
            ÅkJ //   Remove the first and last items | 5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9Cmw1sVDm8KVTjcmu2lcGgdiPr/3wQA)

---

The solution that takes `n` is also 14 bytes:

```
õ òU¬ ÅkJ ®ÅkJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///BWhcObQg@tUTjcmu2lcGgdiPr/39AMAA)

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 85 bytes

```
@for /l %%i in (3,1,%1)do @for /l %%j in (3,1,%1)do @cmd/cset/a(%%i-2)*%1+%%j-1&echo(
```

I can't easily loop from `2` to `m-1` so I loop from `3` to `m` and adjust in the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 26 bytes

```
n->[x|x<-[n..n^2-n],x%n>1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P1y66oqbCRjc6T08vL85INy9Wp0I1z84w9n9afpFGHlCNoY6CiY5CQVFmXgmQr6Sgawck0jTyNDU1/wMA)

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 12 bytes

I spent so long golfing the extraction of elements that I ran out of time to golf the array generation. I'm also only now noticing that we can take `n` as input instead so I may be able to save something there. To be revisited
...

```
òUnU²)òU m¤c
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=8lVuVbIp8lUgbaRj&input=OAotUQo=)

---

### Explanation

```
                 :Implicit input of integer U=m     :e.g., 4
   U²            :U squared                         :16
 Un              :Minus U                           :12
ò                :Range [U,U**2-U]                  :[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
      òU         :Partitions of length U            :[[4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11],[12]]
         m       :Map
          ¤      :  Remove first 2 elements         :[[6,7],[10,11],[]]
           c     :Flatten                           :[6,7,10,11]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
‼ȯTthS↑CN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HDnhPrQ0oygh@1TXT2@///vykA)

### Explanation

```
‼ȯTthS↑CN  Implicit input, say m=4.
       CN  Cut the natural numbers by m: [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],..
     S↑    Take first m lists: [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
‼ȯ         Do this twice:
    h       Remove last row,
   t        remove first row,
  T         transpose.
           Result is [[6,7],[10,11]]; print it implicitly.
```

Answer (score 2):

### TI-BASIC, <s>44</s> 43 bytes (tokenized)

```
DC 4D 3F CE 4D 6D 32 3F CF 3F DE 2A 08 09 3F D0 3F 4D 71 32 3F 23 4D 70 32 70 58 70 32 B1 58 83 72 11 2B 58 2B 30 2B 72 0D 71 31
```

Readable version:

```
:Input M
:If M≤2
:Then
:Disp "{}
:Else
:M-2
:seq(M+2+X+2int(X/Ans),X,0,Ans²-1
```

---

It was unfortunately necessary to print empty lists manually since TI-BASIC does not normally allow that. If `m` were given greater than two, the code could be reduced to just **29 bytes**.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 10 bytes

```
mtPdtPcQS*
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=mtPdtPcQS%2a&input=4&debug=0)**

Takes **m** as input.

Comment: [Alternative](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fg%25TQ2%7DQ-%2a&input=4&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/java8-2100321.html), <s>241</s> <s>183</s> <s>170</s> <s>162</s> <s>160</s> <s>132</s> 122 bytes

```
j->{if(j<3)return new int[1];int e[]=new int[j*j-4*j+4],x=0,i=0;for(;++i<=j*j;)if(!(i<j|i>j*j-j|i%j<2))e[x++]=i;return e;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZPfboIwFMbveYozkiXFCoHp/qVg4gPsykvCRafVtYNiSnUax7OzImwhxpilvTnJ1/6@06/pEXRP/XLLpFh9Ntvde86XsMxpVcEb5fLkOGAWl5qpNV0ymMPprPRqmgFFpgL3yFmvnY6oNNXGaQ4UEmiEPzvxNRLxxFNM75QEyb7OfJSRFmdplvxKYiT86UjgaTY@JOGYJyFZlwoRjHmcmE3iGas7xGPxzWftYVPvRfzgeSw9YJwlnPRNGKkbYu7Tx@rvtC/5CgoTDi204nLTZlCbyhsk2xpdz5WiR0QDiiKvT9euxbHSrAjKnQ7Ox3KJBrsX5IM1ObEmp9bkozX5ZE0@W5Mv1uSrNRmF/0PrbgqufLyBYTc/xfDjXToiN3UHDc0cQDduZqpCYkoMRZAzudEf4ENkFIyHflc9i5RngMEdw9C7dm4AwybZ7RdwM/fvEermBw)

Java makes it very tough(lots of bytes) when you have to create an array of somewhat "unknown" size.

- -8 bytes thanks to Magic Octopus Urn
- -28 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder
- -10 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

Comment: Also, yes, Java is rough for code-golf. But you're obviously good at it. Man, you need to check out this language called `Groovy` it's basically shorthand Java.

Comment: [132 bytes](https://tio.run/##nZNdb8IgFIbv@yvOmiyhsjZ2uq/QmvgDduVl0wum6GD9MBSdpva3d9h2CzHGLHADeeF5Dy/hCLqnfrllhVh9tdvdR8aXsMxoVcE75UXtOKAHLxSTa7pkMIe6UwY1SYEiPQP3SKc3Tk9UiirtNAcKMbTCn9V8jUQ08SRTO1lAwb47PkxJZ8PiX0WMhD8dCTztduAQj8m6lH0RvcaYR7E@QzxteId4JE4nPjtD58W9iB49r2bJAeM05qQZyjHStETfbAg43G5f8hXkOiZaKMmLzTmN3FSekXGrdTWXkh4RDSgKvSHneSyOlWJ5UO5U0B3LCmTsXpCP1uTEmpxak0/W5LM1@WJNvlqTb9ZkOP4f2vT9cOXjGYZ9J@Xmx7t0RG7iGgV1S0DfE7q/xkRPEeRBxoqN@gQfQq1gbPpd9cwTngIG9wFM78a5AZhF0tsv4Kbu3yM07Q8) by removing an extra condition from the if statement, and various tricks.

Comment: [122 bytes](https://tinyurl.com/y75xupc8) continuing _@Mr.Xcoder_'s 132-byte version above by combining the `int`, changing the `||` to `|`, and removing the brackets of the single-line if-body.

Comment: [101 bytes](https://tio.run/##nZPfboIwFMbveYoTki1ghcB0fwsuPsCuvCRcdFpdOyimVKcxPDsrQpbGGLO0N22@nt93eppzONmToNpSwVff7Xb3WbAlLAtS1/BBmDg5DujFhKJyTZYU5nA6K4Oa5UA8vQPz8VlvnJ6oFVHaaQ4EUmh5MDt1UTTLU0F/ziRPJu/xGx/xYDriaJqPD2k0ZmmE15X0MEMo0XfYZ2uPzVJ@z5K0i9WHOz6LfZodEMpThiVVOymA4qbFOvVQwZB@X7EVlLoOb6EkE5vuuXJT@0YRW62ruZTk6JGQeLE/FNKtxbFWtAyrnQrPYYXwjNsL8sGanFiTU2vy0Zp8siafrckXa/LVmoyj/6FN3/BXGs8w7EelNBvv0tFzM9dIqKcA@snSAxRhvSVQhgUVG/UFAcRaQcj0u@pZZiwHBO4YTO/GuQGYSfLbP@Dm7t8nNO0v "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <strike>63</strike> 62 bytes

```
f: func[n][repeat i(n - 2 * n)[if(a: n + i)// n > 1[print a]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcg7CoAwEAXA3lM8rBJFxF9j4SFsly2CZiHNIkHPHyWCdsNEv6fV7yBOMkMu3UiZoj@8OxGMokGPCmopiHEzFDWCbdsHCzo6YtATjpnTy1LMYMtCMBRfjDnGP6YcU7oB)

This is a Red port of totallyhuman's Haskell / Mr. Xcoder's Python 2 solution

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (<s>63</s> 55 bytes)

```
m=>[...Array((m-2)*m)].map((x,i)=>i+m).filter(x=>x%m>1)
```

### Explanation

```
m =>                    // function signature is m
    [...Array((m-2)*m)] // create an array of size m^2 - 2m,
                        // m^2 is the full array size, taking out 2m removes the top and bottom edges
                        // filled with undefined
    .map((x,i)=>i+m)    // fill with values m to n-m
                        // (skips the top and bottom edges of the square)
    .filter(x=>x%m>1)   // filter out x%m < 2, the left and right sides of the square
```

Comment: You only use `n` once, so you can just use `m*m` directly. Also, the JavaScript (ES6) tips page has a tip for getting rid of `fill`.

Comment: You're right `n=m*m` is a holdover from a previous iteration when I had multiple references to `n`. And thanks for the tip on `.fill`, I figured there was a way to golf it, but I hadn't considered `[...Array(x)]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
ĐĐ⁻⁻ř*⇹⁻⁻ř⁺ɐ+
```

Port of [Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154708/77078)

Explanation:

```
                    Implicit input (takes m)
ĐĐ                  Triplicate the input (push it on the stack two more times)
  ⁻⁻                Decrement top of stack twice
    ř               Push [1,2,...,m-2]
     *              Multiplies by m
      ⇹             Swaps top two items on stack
       ⁻⁻           Decrement (m-2 is now on top)
         ř          Push [1,2,...,m-2]
          ⁺         Increment each element by 1
           ɐ+       Add [2,3,...,m-1] to each element of [m,2m,...,m(m-2)]
                    Implicit print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIQjEx417gaiozO1HrXvhLEfNe46OUH7/39TAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
perl -E 'say$_+=@a+2for(@a=2..~-<>)x@a' <<< 4
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, 47 bytes

```js
  m=>{for(i=m;++i<m*m-m;)if(i%m>1)console.log(i)} // here's the 47-byte script
```

Also, 49 bytes:

```js
  m=>{for(i=m;(i%m>1&&console.log(i))|++i<m*m-m;);} // here's the 49-byte script
```

Comment: Your solution presumes the input is assigned to a predefined variable, which we don't permit.

Comment: Not only that, but this solution isn't a function or a full program and relies on other variables and values. For this to be considered valid, either rewrite this as a function or a full program (asking for input with `prompt()`). Here's a sub-optimal 55 bytes long solution for you: `(m,a=[])=>{for(i=m;++i<m*m-m;)if(i%m>1)a[i]=i;return a}`

Comment: Fixed in accordance with rules.

Comment: You can golf it further by switching to an arrow function: `m=>{for(i=m;++i<m*m-m;)if(i%m>1)console.log(i)}`, 47 bytes.

Comment: `alert` is shorter than `console.log`. Welcome to PPCG, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 45 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$m=[i\\i<-[m..m*m-m]|i rem m>1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r4xLJdc2OjMmJtNGNzpXTy9XK1c3N7YmU6EoNVch184w9n9wSSJQsa2CivH/f8lpOYnpxf91PX3@u1TmJeZmJhcDAA)

This is just [totallyhuman's Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154687/18730) but in Clean.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 111 bytes

```
def f(s):
 r=[]
 for i in[i[1:-1]for i in[[(j*s)+i+1 for i in range(s)]for j in range(s)][1:-1]]:r+=i
 return r
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 28 Bytes

Will run given value for `m`

```
1 1↓¯1 ¯1↓m m⍴⍳m*2
```

[Try it...](http://tryapl.com/?a=f%u2190%7B1%201%u2193%AF1%20%AF1%u2193%u2375%20%u2375%u2374%u2373%u2375*2%7D%20%u235D%20call%20the%20function%20by%20typing%20%27f%20%3Cinteger%3E%27&run)

#### Explanation

`m*2` squares m

`⍳m*2` gets list from 1 to m*2

`m m⍴⍳m*2` wraps list to m by m matrix

`¯1 ¯1↓m m⍴⍳m*2` drops -last row an column

`1 1↓¯1 ¯1↓m m⍴⍳m*2` drops first row and column

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you provide some way to test the submission, such as a link to an online interpreter so that others can tell that it is a working solution?