# Borders of a Rectangular Matrix

Tags: code-golf, number, matrix

Although it's done a few times as sub-challenge of a larger challenge, and we also have [a challenge to remove the borders of a square matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/154686/perfect-squares-without-borders), I couldn't find a challenge to output the borders of a given matrix, so here it is.

### Challenge:

Given a rectangular-shaped matrix containing integers as input, output its borders.

### Challenge rules:

- The input is guaranteed to be a rectangular-shaped matrix (or empty)
- The input can contain negative and duplicated integers
- The output format and type is flexible and can be in any order (e.g. `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` may result in `[1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9]`; or `[[1,2,3],[6,9],[8,7],[4]]`; or `9\n8\n7\n6\n4\n3\n2\n1\n`; etc.). As long as it's clear that just the border of the input-matrix is output, *almost* every output-format is allowed. (If you're unsure whether an output format is allowed, feel free to ask in the comments.)

### General Rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (e.g. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Test Cases:

| Input | Output | Visualized |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ``` [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]] ``` | `[1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9]` | [image] |
| `[[]]` | `[]` | N/A |
| `[[0]]` | `[0]` | [image] |
| ``` [[ 9, 2,-5, 3], [18, 3, 8, 0], [ 2, 7,21,-3], [ 9,-5,10,99]] ``` | `[9,2,-5,3,18,0,2,-3,9,-5,10,99]` | [image] |
| `[[1,2,3]]` | `[1,2,3]` | [image] |
| ``` [[9], [8], [8], [9]] ``` | `[9,8,8,9]` | [image] |
| ``` [[ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60], [ 70, 80, 90,-90,-80,-70], [-60,-50,-40,-30,-20,-10]] ``` | ``` [10,20,30,40,50,60,70, -70,-60,-50,-40,-30,-20,-10] ``` | [image] |
| ``` [[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [ 7, 8, 9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16,17,18], [19,20,21,22,23,24], [25,26,27,28,29,30], [31,32,33,34,35,36], [37,38,39,40,41,42], [43,44,45,46,47,48], [49,50,51,52,53,54], [55,56,57,58,59,60]] ``` | ``` [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,12,13,18, 19,24,25,30,31,36,37,42,43, 48,49,54,55,56,57,58,59,60] ``` | [image] |
| ``` [[-11, 18, 3,-40,123], [ 18,-33, 9,765,100]] ``` | `[-11,18,3,-40,123,18,-33,9,765,100]` | [image] |
| ``` [[14, 3], [ 3,14], [14, 3], [ 3,14], [14, 3]] ``` | `[14,3,3,14,14,3,3,14,14,3]` | [image] |

Comment: I think it would be good to add `2xN` or `Nx2` example to the test cases.

Comment: The visualization in the last test case seems really garbled.

Comment: @erfink Fixed, thanks for noticing.

Comment: @BartoszJabłoński Added.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Fixed. The hyperlinks is something SE does automatically for `[1]`, `[2]`, etc. for the images.. I changed the `[8]` and `[9]` image ids to `80` and `90` so I won't have to change the test case.. :/

Comment: Are duplicate values of the boundaries allowed?

Comment: @AZTECCO No sorry, the amount of items should correspond with the amount of items in the borders (so it's not allowed to simply output the first and last rows and columns, since the corners would be twice each in the output). How you format those different items is completely up to you, though (see the third challenge rule, or the existing answers, for examples of what's allowed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `W`, 6 bytes

```
ḣṫ$ᵛÞh
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJXIiwiIiwi4bij4bmrJOG1m8OeaCIsIiIsIltbIDEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDUsIDZdLFsgNywgOCwgOSwxMCwxMSwxMl0sWzEzLDE0LDE1LDE2LDE3LDE4XSxbMTksMjAsMjEsMjIsMjMsMjRdLFsyNSwyNiwyNywyOCwyOSwzMF0sWzMxLDMyLDMzLDM0LDM1LDM2XSxbMzcsMzgsMzksNDAsNDEsNDJdLFs0Myw0NCw0NSw0Niw0Nyw0OF0sWzQ5LDUwLDUxLDUyLDUzLDU0XSxbNTUsNTYsNTcsNTgsNTksNjBdXSIsIjMuNC4yIl0=)

Abuses formatting quite a bit but there isn't a way to get diagonals yet.

```
ḣṫ$ᵛÞh­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
ḣ       # ‎⁡head extract
 ṫ$     # ‎⁢tail extract and swap 
   ᵛÞh  # ‎⁣vectorized edges
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: uh i just realized i didn't program edges correctly for single element lists so i have to fix that but otherwise it works

Answer (score 8):

## Python 3, 38 bytes

```
def f(x):
 for c in x[1:-1]:c[1:-1]=[]
```

[Outputs by modifying arguments](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/70761). The code also works on Python 2.

Explanation: deletes the center part of each center row by modifying the original input.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVPLbttADDz05q_gKbCAWcDc9xrolwhC0aZ264sSKAqQfEsvuST_1H5NZ7VOgVYqDGrXJIfkDKUfb_fP8_e78eXl9XE-m_zz5uvpLOf9U3fcyfluklu5jPLU69HocLxt58d-aNm_Pnyp6fPpYd5fFgSPnUyn-XEa5bK7ny7jvF_Cfa-wcAN6j4DIMyGjDEPX_Z12AH9rtxJhaW4TUYOwG6jaE34J80SoFdAmWCWvPOtOiySfqiTT5_HbaR-74V9X6FYwKRALEyDkv5NeM28QPg_LfwYlwSpMizOfyXpA2dCnybhylwHS5z-PDaCwoFiao3laoMXrBIn3TCsHmGq8m9RiJvLOXEOMIdawhtGNFYlWmpWZZ3HWvpZemJbKRxVqmwQO6qFkGaEJmpu3gMUphOU2HaxfvDbARlgqlGELXBvLKRyVcHAeLsC1bi7BZbgCDusVvnXz3LmHD_ARPsG3br6AtIIiWASH0LqFgBAREkJGKIgbRA15SF0iuVZV1F73Rp_hREK2KdYNbr3I_v01kKpB4_1fH-HtU3v_QH8D) (additional test cases taken from [loopy walt's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260961))

Comment: On the output of test case `print(test(5*[6*[0]]))`, shouldn't the first and last items have 6 zeroes?

Comment: @Jonah Oh, that appears to be an issue with the test case, not with the solution itself (due to the list containing multiple references to the same sublist). I've replaced it with a fixed version.

Comment: Got it, nice solution.

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>10</s> 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I/O as a 2D array of integers, with output sorted anti-clockwise starting in the bottom right corner.

```
4Æ=z)oÃf
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=NMY9eilvw2Y&input=W1sgMSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNSwgNl0sCiBbIDcsIDgsIDksMTAsMTEsMTJdLAogWzEzLDE0LDE1LDE2LDE3LDE4XSwKIFsxOSwyMCwyMSwyMiwyMywyNF0sCiBbMjUsMjYsMjcsMjgsMjksMzBdLAogWzMxLDMyLDMzLDM0LDM1LDM2XSwKIFszNywzOCwzOSw0MCw0MSw0Ml0sCiBbNDMsNDQsNDUsNDYsNDcsNDhdLAogWzQ5LDUwLDUxLDUyLDUzLDU0XSwKIFs1NSw1Niw1Nyw1OCw1OSw2MF1dCi1R)

```
4Æ=z)oÃf     :Implicit input of 2D array U
4Æ           :Map the range [0,4)
  =          :  Reassign to U
   z         :   Rotate U 90° clockwise
    )        :  End reassignment
     o       :  Pop last sub-array, mutating the array
      Ã      :End map
       f     :Filter, removing null elements
```

Answer (score 6):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), <s>57</s> <s>46</s> 20 bytes

```
del(.[1:-1][][1:-1])
```

[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Y-niTUhPziP)

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! Nice first answer, so +1 from me. :) Enjoy your stay and best of luck with other challenges.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 54 bytes

```javascript
m=>m.map((r,y)=>r.filter((_,x)=>x*y/r[x+1]?!m[y+1]:1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDBbsIwDIbvPEV3a7c/rI7jpJkEe5CqmtAGExOlqKAJnp65NBw2wQ5OHMf2Z/9fi@/F/r1f7w5m230sz6vZuZ3N22m72OV5j1Mxm/fT1XpzWPZ5/oajvo@Pp@e@Pj5R8/rQ1ie9X6gozu/ddt9tltNN95mv8nqSZTXBghsMroPAj25AhdhMmqKY/Kmpm1vB8lZ0aJRFZBZGkCUIVeoi07McA/qdBViCSRlaovlUIt6ZYBz5DjCOTapf1@1GF5hyMqvGak5N1Px1tKCPSi2WMIOpb0L6NF4fmm20ymi10S6Gyn9IgxLD7k4pCrkyLmLEYWEikE0yMciBVAcPCqC0CEUoRsWyFpZh3Ri2AuthVcYKNoLTiExglYrBDizghOQArsAROrkjuIR0DOfgBM7DBbiEdBG6pRDEQhiSkCIQDwmQChLhx8XPPw)

Or **58 bytes** (ES10) if we want to flatten the output:

```javascript
m=>m.flatMap((r,y)=>r.filter((_,x)=>x*y/r[x+1]?!m[y+1]:1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDdbsIwDIXveYrurt1OWB3np5kEe4I9QVVNFaMTU6GooAmevnNpuNgEu3DiOLY/@3zV3/Vh1W/2R7XrPtZDsxi2i@V23rT18a3ep2mPc7ZY9vNm0x7XfZq@4yTv0@P5uS9PT1S9PmzLs9wvlGXDqtsdunY9b7vPtEnLWZKUBA2uMLoGFm5yPQqEalZl2exPTVndCua3omOjJCDRUBZJhFAhLhI58ykg34mHJqiYISWSTznCnQmmke8Aw9Sk@HXdbnSBCSfRYixmxKyYu47m5VGIhRxqNPGVj5/KyUOylVQpqVbSRVH@D2lUYtzdCEUgV8ZFjDAuTATSUSYGGZDo4EAeFBehAMGIWFpDM7SZwtpCO2iRsYAO4DgiE1ikYrABW3BEsgcX4ACZ3BBMRBqGMTAWxsF4mIg0AbKlJVgNy7ARaS2sg/WwBWyAmxYffgA)

#### Commented

```javascript
m =>                 // m[] = input matrix
m.map((r, y) =>      // for each row r[] in m[] at index y:
  r.filter((_, x) => //   for each value in r[] at index x:
    x * y            //     if neither x nor y is equal to 0 and there's
    / r[x + 1] ?     //     at least one more column after this one:
      !m[y + 1]      //       keep the value only if this is the last row
    :                //     else:
      1              //       keep the value
  )                  //   end of filter()
)                    // end of map()
```

Comment: The ouput format is pretty loose, so 54 bytes should be valid.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>24</sup> 20 bytes

```
#~&,_>_(<,~<<0 _1)}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/levUdOLt4jVsdOpsbAwU4g01a2P/a3KlJmfkK6QpZOqZKJiCOerqMDEdPUt0EStDBSMFY0x1ChZAaPkfAA)

- `_(<,~<<0 _1)}]` Convert all interior points to infinity, by specifying "not first and last (0 and -1)" elements of first axis, and "not first and last" elements of second axis.
- `_>` Where is that matrix less than infinity?  Returns a 1-0 mask selecting the border
- `#~&,` Flatten and filter the input with that mask

## alternative, 20 bytes

```
#~&,]+./&(#\e.1,#)|:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/levUdGK19fTVNJRjUvUMdZQ1a6z@a3KlJmfkK2TqmSiYQphpSBx1dZiYjp4luoiVoYKRgjGmOgULILT8DwA)

## diagonal rotation, 24 bytes

```
#~&,_=[:+/,.~@1 _1|.!._]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYzNCoJQEIX3PsWkol4cR28/kNMVLgWtokXbEBehZJsewJ9Xt9sFiYphBs75zpzH5FLYQMEQAkIGbDYhOFxOx8kbA6yKK8cp0qglVLKnBVXlJJzznuCNFWs/C2rS3LvS97gl7VvYGRglZI7CUanMPIugE/oTIIN240wwwI4t8ONUR0WKskhLIeOvUjIhNM1yYD1QZLVwpVPf7k9ooKU1bKwIw9lDyn8dlrCE1X8Otmby6QU)

Looks like this may be related to Adam's APL answer, but was discovered independently.  See alternate below for a different approach.

1. Diagonally rotate the matrix up-left using infinity as fill.
2. Same thing down-right
3. Add the two together (now the borders will all have the value infinity)
4. Create a border-selecting 1-0 mask with 1 wherever infinity is
5. Use that mask to filter the input, flattening both the mask and the input

## original, 24 bytes

```
#~&,0=<:@$*/@:|"1$#:i.@$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZczNCsIwDAfw@54ibGVbXZe2foCrLRQFT@LBu3iQDefFB5jbq9euMPwiJJD8/uTuYswaMAoyYCBA@S4RdqfD3iVDyoTRypIZt@oZS5KoFi1xNDpuEUYeUaQ1fnLAzmNeoh@aDVoLuEiadtS@A@hpM0zCUtapAKTgNjecScPPVBZfT9GHmP8se2V7zMNOYxnV19sDGmhxCauwZNl0Y1j9XpSEOSz@c7D2VbkX)

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>47</s> 45 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @alephalpha

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNa8MwDIbv@RWGQOk6h9rOBwshpdfuVEZuRgNvdVcf4hRHN5P@9SzL2FZ3BV1e9DxCUqvwpFuF5l2Nb507aFePu6NsnOSvMWwE9bGUWHtOEz4A0CmJqkoERYCBxrAYUffISU32yqFB01n5ouyHliVQkkIVfU@VMwbr9d4Zi1H0FcVkeT8MASNCJp0ZdgOlIZRNUOOU7c9dr7fel5Q8zVXeeFno5fXf0kvOVj@LP1yeO2Mvy4QzRh7JdYeSIrwpD0cWdz5RMPinFb/a@Ak)

```
If[Tr[1^#]>2,{#[[t={1,-1}]],#[[2;;-2,t]]},#]&
```

**Explanation**

`Tr[1^#]` returns the length of the shortest dimension by computing the `Trace` of a matrix of 1's with the same dimensions as the input, i.e., `Min@Dimensions@#`. If we have an edge case with a dimension of 0, 1, or 2, we return the input in its original form.

If `Tr[1^#]>2` is true, then we use Mathematica's `[[a;;b, c;;d]]` syntax to access different parts of the matrix: `#[[{1,-1}]]` returns the first and last rows, `#[[2;;-2,{1,-1}]]` returns the first and last columns while excluding the "corners." We return a ragged array as the output: if the input is `m`x`n` with `m`,`n>2`, the output will be of the format `{(2 x n array), ((m-2) x 2 array)}`

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms Thanks--longtime listener, first time caller!

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! According to [tag:code-golf]'s rule, answers should be either a full program or a function. `If[Tr[1^m]>2,{m[[{1,-1}]],m[[2;;-2,{1,-1}]]},m]` isn't a function by itself. You can write `If[Tr[1^#]>2,{#[[{1,-1}]],#[[2;;-2,{1,-1}]]},#]&`.

Comment: You can save some bytes by storing `{1,-1}` in a variable: `If[Tr[1^#]>2,{#[[t={1,-1}]],#[[2;;-2,t]]},#]&`.

Comment: @alephalpha Thanks, changed to a pure function. Wasn't quite sure what moves were legal, e.g., taking input as a previously declared variable, and tried to emulate some Mathematica answers from other questions. It won't happen again! As for storing `t={1,-1}`, do I need to worry about localizing `t` and variables in general? I.e., do codegolf rules allow side effects?

Comment: @erfink Changing a global variable is allowed as long as your function is [reusable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4939/9288).

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

*With the lax output requirements I was expecting to find terser in Jelly!*

```
ŒDị@Ḋ¡€.
```

A monadic Link that accepts the rectangular matrix and yields a list of lists of border values.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJJeHu7sdHu7oOrTwUdMavf@H249Oerhzxv//0dEKhgY6CkZAbAzEJkBsCsRmBrE6XArRCuZAtgUQWxro6IIwkK1rDpHTNQOygWp1gXp0gXp1gWboGoLkYgE)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##TU87TsQwEO33FC5okJ5RxjNjxwWIAolDRClpVnsBuoUGCbqtKKCgp16BkCiC9iDJRcIkzkpbPGccv3mf9d1mcz@Oh91N//Ny3X89dx/D4@fFeIu/p8Ou/349Ww/bt25/eeWG7fv5enj47fbdfhybVdMQXIDjFivXCJzCxXlOcDVcbu3SNOWsysflacXrcYuMxzO7mu@TXkIg@PJufCNThbyoEQK4jHlm1CfnwnHGd8HABjGoIS4GyebakCv4CTb7VN58tNm43na87XrT8HRMvpQ1xZOmbqk6RSQChdKKQQKy4BGUQCUdZZigdQsBgRFk/hsUISJY6Rohg0sUJrAVZbCAFVzcOIFrcIYFFIIUN2GIQBQSIQlS3CTDqihBA5ShxU0VGqEJWkMz4lyu/Qc).

#### How?

```
ŒDị@Ḋ¡€. - Link: list of lists, M
ŒD       - all NW-SE diagonals of M
       . - set the right argument to 0.5
      €  - for each diagonal:
     ¡   -   repeat...
    Ḋ    -   ...number of times: dequeue (i.e. once if diagonal length > 1)
   @     -   ...action: with swapped arguments - f(0.5, diagonal)
  ị      -                index into*
             
             * fractional indices give the two neighbours in the 
               case of 0.5 that's 0 (the last) and 1 (the first)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Excel, 77 bytes

```
=TOCOL(B2#/(MAP(B2#,LAMBDA(b,SUM(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(b,{-1;1},{-1,1})))))<4),2)
```

Input is spilled range deliberately set to have its top-leftmost cell as `B2`, rather than the customary `A1`, such that the four cells above, below, to the right and to the left of that cell exist.

Answer (score 4):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 81 bytes

```rust
|a,b,c|(0..).zip(a).filter(move|(d,_)|d%b<1||d%b>b-2||d/b<1||d/b>c-2).map(|a|a.1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVBBasMwELz7FZtAQYK1YjsNjVVXvfTaQy-9lGJkWQaB7RhbySFRXlIKPrSPym8qx4V2WWZ2h2FY9uOr3w92vDxVLTTStITCKai1hYpXLXnVKjODOWqB-4lmpKEYbMm5sbrn_Fl2WY65gAf43tsq3F5enMQClSMRY5QdTUckZZWpvZ00u4N2pMScuvKmyGI3kSjCxA-reV8VQoUJZY3siJNOspj-Bn_eB0HXm9bW7YIsT_zxvESoSAAAB60Wb5AiJBhuENYIG5z0a8Xbq-IxQrj7073Zr0mM4Rrj5J-eTiFxhGnqO32fwuCWMrWra60s55l_jMf5NYJQ6g87z0eO48w_)

Takes input as a flattened matrix with size given as `b` and `c`

Comment: `d%b%(b-1)<1||d/b%(c-1)<1` saves 6 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [SAS IML](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/imlug/titlepage.htm), 88 <s>70</s>

Input is a rectangular matrix `M` e.g.,

```
M1={
 1  2  3  4  5  6,
 7  8  9 10 11 12,
13 14 15 16 17 18,
19 20 21 22 23 24,
25 26 27 28 29 30,
31 32 33 34 35 36,
37 38 39 40 41 42,
43 44 45 46 47 48,
49 50 51 52 53 54,
55 56 57 58 59 60
};
```

[EDIT:]
According to comments below I updated the answer.

The code (an IML module):

```
start d(M);if 2<nrow(M)><ncol(M) then M[2:nrow(M)-1,2:ncol(M)-1]=.;M=M[loc(M>.)];finish;
```

Human readable:

```
start d(M);
  if 2 < nrow(M)><ncol(M) then 
    M[ 2:nrow(M)-1, 2:ncol(M)-1 ] = .; 
  M = M[ loc(M > .) ];
finish;
```

To execute the IML module `d` run the following:

```
call d(M);
```

The process:

1. For a Matrix M with at least 3 rows and columns (`2 < nrow(M)><ncol(M)`, where `nrow(M)` is number of rows, `ncol(M)` is number of columns, and `><` is operator of minimum of two numbers) replace "everytnig inside" (`2:nrow(M)-1, 2:ncol(M)-1`) with missing data (`.`),
2. select those elements of `M` where value is not missing.

To print out result, i.e. elements extracted from `M`, run the following line:

```
if type(M)="U" then print "M is Empty";
else print M;
```

---

Comment: Nice answer, +1 from me. Never heard of this language before, but it's fitting you've solved a matrix-based challenge with a programming language that has an abbreviation IML, which stands for [Interactive Matrix Language](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/imlug/imlug_imlstart_sect001.htm) apparently. :)

Comment: Yes, IML is SAS dedicated matrix language, in fact it is one of many SAS data processing "dialects". There is great blog series "the DO loop" by Rick Wicklin explaining and presenting various IML use-cases: https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/ Worth reading.

Comment: Your submission must get input either via function parameter, STDIN, or command-line argument; you may not assume that a variable is defined.

Comment: Updated. The keywords `start` and `finish` plus name `d(M)` extended length by 18 bytes, so ~25.7%.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>44</s> 34 bytes

```r
\(m)m[rev(d<-row(m)<2|col(m)<2)|d]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZBLCsIwEIZx21MEVwnMQNJWbYquvYA7dSF9iGAVQn0svImbKngoPY1_LeiilfBlHv8_Gcj15qp7PnkcypyjZ38hC1XMXXaU6Zjd_oRy7F-S_faTqEu6bJyv3lQWk2JVus1ZmthSQDRTysvh837KZldm68xJ1ZZ0u5VIS8InHpAIyBMmqqPArVFBECPyDXGtCVvbjCZrFYWdu00ckOleEuFgrlvGo8IHAQjBAAzBCETAauIa5IweQ2N4GF7GDGOWjVZ_fsTE8GPFV2v-s6qa-AY)

Footer stolen from [pajonk's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260945/64121), and -10 thanks to them!

Comment: Actually, with this approach you don't really need to rotate the matrix - simple `rev` is sufficient, because `|d` does the conversion back to matrix for you. [ATO!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZBLCsIwEIZx21MEVwnMQNJWbYquvYA7dSF9iGAVQn0svImbKngoPY1_LeiilfBlHv8_Gcj15qp7PnkcypyjZ38hC1XMXXaU6Zjd_oRy7F-S_faTqEu6bJyv3lQWk2JVus1ZmthSQDRTysvh837KZldm68xJ1ZZ0u5VIS8InHpAIyBMmqqPArVFBECPyDXGtCVvbjCZrFYWdu00ckOleEuFgrlvGo8IHAQjBAAzBCETAauIa5IweQ2N4GF7GDGOWjVZ_fsTE8GPFV2v-s6qa-AY)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 62 [bits<sup>v1</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 7.75 bytes

```
4(∩ḣṘ)_W'
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyI9IiwiIiwiNCjiiKnhuKPhuZgpX1cnIiwiIiwiW1s5XSwgWzhdLCBbOF0sIFs5XV0iXQ==)

Port of pyth messed up by the fact that `ḣ` and `ṫ` return `0` on an empty list instead of erroring (which has its use, but is annoying here)

### Explained

```
4(∩ḣṘ)_W'
4(   )    # 4 times
  ∩       #   transpose top of stack
   ḣ      #   separate the head from the rest
    Ṙ     #   and reverse
      _W  # pop the remaining list and wrap the stack in a list
        ' # remove 0s and empty lists
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ŒDµżṪḢ)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU87TsQwFOz3FG5XGkt5PzvuuQSKtqRBewFOQL8VNSU9EkhUoD3IniRM7CBRvJdx3ryZeY8P5/PTul4vd9/v16/b59vt4/W4/jxfL7fPl@P9ui6HZREo7IRDWhyB0lHFjHYiXJbRp/FJDUmRA2lsyEyExD71N4epQgV5zMknWSa0XW2Yddg6Y/7Xd04iPynLWM4KVtkNKvHMahPyVsS5jlkuxORm7mTuZmpk@UsuW/ItrFOQertcD9@2iCIQHVcZxCEMXiAVMtJJAwV5myrUoN7/akALlEfP0AYbUUxgPNRgDgvYcLMKm2ENDOgCH25ucIcHvMArfLh5A08JQSjCEMMtAlEQFTEjGko/7vQL)

No shot I could have thought of using diagonals if @Jonathan Allan hadn't first, so go upvote [his solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/261008/85334)! (Also, two bonus 8-byters: `ŒDµṙ-ḣ2)`, `ŒDµḊṖœ^)`)

```
ŒDµ   )    For each diagonal of the input:
    Ṫ      take and remove the last element,
   ż       zip with the remaining elements,
     Ḣ     and take the first of those pairs.
```

My original solutions, to laugh at:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ḊṖ$⁺€Fœ^F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU8xTsQwEOzvFS5okMZS1rtrxx@4P6AodDToPkAJDRIlSIhH8ACOFt1D7j4SJnaQKHYzzs7OzN7fHQ4Py3L@ejkf368uj9@Xp8/96e12v/w8n17Px4/rm2WZdtMkSNAZuzAZHLmhghF1Jpym3of@CRUhITpC35CRCIF9aG8OQ0ESxD4nn2QZUDe1btZgbYzxX984gfyQWMoylrPyZlCIR1YdENcijqXPYiYmN3IncjdSI8pfclmTr2GNgtTb5Fr4ukYUgaR@lUIMwuAZUiA9nVRQkLelhKRI1v4mR8pIPHpEqtAeRQXKQxVqUId2Ny3QEVrBgCaw7mYKM5jDMqzAuptV8BQXeIIrvLu5wzO8wEd4RW7Hzb8)

```
ḊṖ           Remove the first and last rows
  $⁺€        and columns.
     F       Flatten the result,
        F    flatten the input,
      œ^     symmetric multiset difference.
```

Can't decide if this feels worse...:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ḊUZƊ3Ð¡ZḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU87TkNBDOxzim2RZqXntb2fg1CQp5Q0KBfgBEipEBUtnCJpieAeOclj3u5DorDf7PN4Zvz0eDw@L8vtfLrf/5z0@vr1sb@dP5fry/fb7fJ@97As826eBQl6wC7MBkfuqKCiHQjnefRpfEJDSIiOMDakEiGwT/3NYShIgjjm5JMsE9qmNsw6bJ1R//WNE8gPiaUsYzkrbwaFuLLahLgWcSxjFjMxuZE7kbuRGlH@ksuafA1rFKTeJtfDtzWiCCSNqxRiEAbPkAIZ6aSBgrwtJSRFsv43OVJG4tEVqUFHFBUoD1WoQR063LRAK7SBAU1gw80UZjCHZViBDTdr4Cku8ARX@HBzh2d4gVd4Q@7HHX4B)

```
   Ɗ3Ð¡      Repeat [0, 1, 2, 3] times:
Ḋ            Remove the first row,
 U           reverse each row,
  Z          transpose.
       Z     Transpose the results
        Ḣ    and return the first row of that.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 18 bytes

Thanks to ovs for −4 bytes.

Anonymous prefix lambda.

```apl
{⍵[⍸∨∘⌽∘⊖⍨1∊¨⍳⍴⍵]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU@9SgNBEO59iu2i8C3c7OzPbW2jFgrG7rgiILEJaCtiJYQQvKBFxEdIIVioYGOTR9kXOWc3JhYzOzs/38/oZqIvb0eT66u@v0vdV5O67zRbpdlrevzJef6SuhWl2Xy9St1H6j5lqb3vx2n6tJ@6RZo/pO5N2ut3TtPntFgOzw8lXxwdDw9yQyAWy5Ph2Wk/HjQNwYBbqMbCwecioEZs28FeHm/faluoCGWgHVS5oloKKMlV/spIBRiCLlNZlk2qEHeAG76/T8xL9S7tlpScKCPBElbCSfgNQ5CylogVdA6pdSgj7aWUTS0XWi61IGj6V05ZeVZrBVDwNnBFfMwiiUCmmGKQBYlyDwqgIo4iBE@sGQPDMDY3jYPxMGK5hongooMJLCYZbMEOXIg4gGtwhIizBFuILMNaWAfrYQNsIbIRYsIRnIFjuELkHJyHC3A1XITPrn4B)

`{`…`}` "dfn"; argument is `⍵`:

`⍵[`…`]` select from the argument:

`⍸` where indicated by

`∨∘⌽∘⊖⍨` the following mask when ORed with its mirrored flipped version…

`1∊¨` true only where 1 is a member of

`⍳` the indices for an array that has the shape

`⍴⍵` the shape of the argument

Comment: I think `{⍵[⍸∨∘⌽∘⊖⍨1∊¨⍳⍴⍵]}` works for 18

Comment: Which file encoding to use for that???

Comment: @Aconcagua See https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9428/43319

Comment: @Aconcagua No, this is Dyalog APL which can use [the SBCS library](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS).

Comment: Ah, I see, there's an explicit 8-bit code page for – utf-8 would have had 14 additional bytes ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua It'd have been 25 additional bytes, but yes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 48 bytes

```hs
b=zipWith($)[head,map last,last,map head].repeat
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P8m2KrMgPLMkQ0NFMzojNTFFJzexQCEnsbhEB0yAeCDhWL2i1ILUxJL/uYmZebYFRZl5JSpJ0dGGOkY6xrE60SY6pjpmQNpcx0LHMjb2PwA)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 74 bytes

```hs
import Data.List;(o:t)#(r:s)=r++t#(reverse$transpose$s);_#_=[];b=("1234"#)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZLCsMgEADQq5SYhZKhkE9/EXdd9gYiwYBQSWJkZuj1rav3vp62sO@lxCOfyJe3Z3/9RGItz5mVkDiTMth1XBt@ASm0jD5RPutI6UUsxjq9Gtn0wzg1QpXDx2QyxsTtam0PA4wO7AQ3uFcf8ISXc@UP)

At each of the four or less iterations, `#` peels the top row `r` from the matrix, and rotates it i-wise by `transpose` sending corner 2 to 3 and `reverse` sending corner 2 from 3 to 1 before reiterating for one side `o` less than before.

Comment: I think yo have to add the wanted function `([1..4]#)`  to the byte count

Comment: Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you , although I like the solution, it seems to produce duplicates values, it's not specified if they are permitted, but I don't think they are

Comment: indeed.  my edit comment was: is this allowed?

Comment: Oh! I see, maybe It's better to make it more visible like specifying it in the answer or asking the OP. Btw I asked OP for clarification. Let's see

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
V4.)=_C
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P8xET9M23vn//@hoQx0jHeNYnWgTHVMdMyBtrmOhYxkbCwA)

Prints each side as lists separated by newlines. Goes clockwise starting with the left side.

#### Explanation

```
V4.)=_CQ    # implicitly add Q
            # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
V4          # loop 4 times
    =  Q    #   assign Q to
      CQ    #   Q transposed
     _      #   and reversed
  .)        #   pop the last element of Q and print it
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 48 bytes

```
f=lambda a:a[:1]+a[1:][-1:]+map(f,a[1:-(a>[f])])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMGCpaUlaboWNw3SbHMSc5NSEhUSrRKjrQxjtROjDa1io3WBhHZuYoFGmg5IQFcj0S46LVYzVhOq72BBUWZeiUaaRnS0oY6RjnGsTrSJjqmOGZA217HQsYyN1dTkQqgx0AFCNDFDoFojIDbGVAuS0TFCVw-yR8cELAekdUxBenUgtqKqROUic0y1os20osEugXgEFhAA)

Takes a LOL and returns a ragged LOL. Output for non degenerate inputs is [top row,bottom row,[1st,last]of 2nd row,[1st,last]of 3rd row,...

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 52 bytes

```r
\(m)m[row(m)%in%c(1,nrow(m))|col(m)%in%c(1,ncol(m))]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZBBCsIwEEVx21NkIyQwA5m2alNw7QXcqQspVgq2Qqnowpu4qYKH0tP4S0AFK-FlMvP_ZGAu17q95dP7ock5ecRLXZpyUe-PiMOiGmZaqPKpOWf73XfZp2ble5-DmS6n5bqpi5OW1FFENDcmyOEJPkpRNZvtptbmV7K_pUw7UiHxiFREgZKkiwq3RQZBTSgU4k5TrrOJJecMxb2zJY1I-ockOOjrl_GpCkEEYjACYzABCXCWuANvRo2hMTwML6OH0ctizZ-NSAo_Rrw1v8-29fEF)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
ＩΣＥθΦι¬∧﹪κ⊖Ｌθ﹪μ⊖Ｌι
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bY7BCoJAEIbvPcXgaYQR1IiUTpF0ygg6Lnsw3VLS3dS1l-nioahX8m1aUDo1h-Hn_7_5mccnzZMmVUnZ969On51g0IemkBo3Savx2FUYJzesCbZFqUWDBcFeaVzLDGOVdaXCK0Ek0kZUQmqR4U7Ii86xtm2bYEKqv0hh_2b1bE9pO33wZpZzLy0-RIwxCAl8chYEc04zAOYFRhKY7Y6GiWFJvkfORJgTw3suhSHnfOz8Ag) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Uses a filter to keep elements in the first or last row or column i.e. those that are not both in an interior row and in an interior column.

```
   θ                Input array
  Ｅ                 Map over rows
     ι              Current row
    Φ               Filtered where
         κ          Current row
        ﹪           Modulo
            θ       Input array
           Ｌ        Length
          ⊖         Decremented
       ∧            Logical And
              μ     Current column
             ﹪      Modulo
                 ι  Current row
                Ｌ   Length
               ⊖    Decremented
      ¬             Logical Not
 Σ                  Flatten
Ｉ                   Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [julia](https://julialang.org/), 59 bytes

Expects a `Matrix{Any}` and returns a `Vector{Any}` of the border entries.

Each call of this function pops the top row of the matrix, rotates the resulting matrix to the right and recurses. Terminates after 4 iterations or when the resulting matrix is empty.

```
f(M,c=4)=length(M)c>0 ? [M[1,:];f(M[end:-1:2,:]',c-1)] : []
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZFLasMwEIbptqf4d5HAgpHfD5LuuqpPILwwjh27GDe4MhTanqSbbHKo9jQdxxSKDSMx-vXPfHp8XZ-nvisvl-tkGxV_Z43InWrvy31fDyfbilxWB8IDTG60kxbzvqmHY6p06vJ651RKywIpTLG0-Ll7aoTRcOFl8BEgzBAhRlJIfBxwHrvB9sM99ynt2L29P_YvpQ39TzENx7pxQBxyZW2r0oqNahKGqGDm6BgeMyhjJYKroVhM5k1NSDbo5Xhr9UYxSYb4Fly1KSO4BI_gEwJCyLyIEDOCoObBqYpYVSEn7FBsVOxXXKY0rYlj_dqW51roNORrC81TKOXuv2t51L__-QU)

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 98 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lU1NS8QwEL3vr5hjwk5K2@03rOBRUC8eZSmxplipSTcJi7Dub6/TaotHN/Am783Me@Ma2cvRvLyrxsOD7DSoT6/0q4PbYYDz5iR7aCv2pI7Pd9ofcCKLOPD9zcJhDyMzeKTW/H1I37ydG@kUsMeux5p/sRqJ/fEw/jOv0VaVo4HdbltmAi/J4AJvpXaDcSqw6qSsU/wybgAG22nfa9YyFoE3kPDAm/vOeYSpsrlEGOOO/3YSTDFbRI4Flpzef6NKhBhFirDmRQUJBKrh0ooRcowjFOtSOXmiEMurjpEBYsKOkBBSQrZeyUkVhDJEMYG4yNepyEiSQZBRUICgIBGF8/nL@A0)

```scala
(o,q)=>(o,q)match{case (Nil,_)|(_,Nil)=>Seq[Int]()case (_,r::s)=>r++f(o.tail,s.transpose.reverse)}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lU5dS8MwFH3frziPCbspbdeu7WCCj4L6B2SM2KWsMtuSBBF0v73elK3uUQPnknNzPuJqfdLj2L@@mdrjSbcdzKc33cHhfhjwtQAOpkEj@g0eW@dfHjq/I1h3ofNuJ28E2EL0QSXxrn19nHKAWjsD8dyeCHuJb4g9gZnE9u7XK@SNlgUWmw3cpLFYLsNXIq9Dhou81Z0bemciaz6MdSZ4zwseg207f@pEI0QC3yOTke9DB01NYhoJpbSSl01GOa2vpKCSKsnnr1EVISWVE@a8pGRC4BlfVymhoDQhNYuq4Eliqv5VxgakjBUjY@SM9dxSMCsZVUwqgO@qmF/VmikbFBsVBygOUkk81Z8X4/gD)

```scala
object Main extends App {
  def f(o: List[Int], rs: List[List[Int]]): List[Int] = (o, rs) match {
    case (Nil, _) | (_, Nil) => List[Int]()
    case (_, r :: s) => r ++ f(o.tail, s.transpose.reverse)
  }

  println(f((1 to 4).toList, List(List(1,2,3), List(4,5,6), List(7,8,9))))
  println(f((1 to 4).toList, List(List(9, 2,-5, 3), List(18, 3, 8, 0), List(2, 7,21,-3), List(9,-5,10,99))))
  println(f((1 to 4).toList, List(List(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60), List(70, 80, 90,-90,-80,-70), List(-60,-50,-40,-30,-20,-10))))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 23 bytes

```
(?<=¶.+)\b\S+\b(?=.+¶)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X8PexvbQNj1tzZikmGDtmCQNe1s97UPbNLn@/7dUMFLQNVUw5jK0UDBWsFAw4DJSMFcwMlTQNeayBMkYGihYWgIA)

Expects a matrix as having columns separated by spaces and rows separated by newlines. Works by removing numbers that have a newline more than immediately before and after them. The boundaries are required to avoid deleting digits/signs elsewhere in the boundary numbers since there isn't a way to make lookahead/behind non-greedy/backtrack (at least in fewer than 4 bytes).

Seems shorter than [listing all boundary](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3ychTk@7Rk9bpSYmWFvD3vbQNs0aDXsbEA0U@P/fUsFIQddUwZjL0ELBWMFCwYDLSMFcwchQQdeYyxIkY2igYGkJAA) numbers, for the same reason. I've found a [slightly crazy](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3ychTk@7Rk9bpSamXPvQtpoY9@g4nVjt//8tdYx04k11jLkMLXSMdSx0DLiMdMx1jAx14o25LEEyhgY6lpYA) version that is a byte shorter, but is also far more abusive of the lax I/O.

```
L`^.+|.+$|\w+¶|\G[^,]+
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>31</s> 29 bytes

Very similar to [SuperStormer’s Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260991/11261). Outputs by modifying the given array.

```ruby
->a{a[r=1..-2].map{_1[r]=[]}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY9NDoIwEIX3nGIO8EpoFSkxdcklJhNTE92ZGISFIZzEDTF6DPdewdtY6AbczN_73kzm_qzbw214VO7VNidl32rnO8-102mqjKRnf-n2mmtxLH0fme-nOV4bcjSyVLGXLXnqk-RCo8DMGgYrQUK8Ro7NVBWwKEVkhmXLlkqQgcpB0attqEAhZlMfRCpgNFTUAx9gnaH82xvPL0bl5LCzOHriP8MQ8w8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 13 bytes

```
⊡⊚↥⇌≡⇌.≡∊0⇡△.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0__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)

Port of Adám's [APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260936/97916).

```
⊡⊚↥⇌≡⇌.≡∊0⇡△.­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
            .  # ‎⁡duplicate
          ⇡△   # ‎⁢coordinate matrix
       ≡∊0     # ‎⁣mask of coordinates that contain zero
   ⇌≡⇌.        # ‎⁤duplicate and reverse both axes
  ↥            # ‎⁢⁡max (logical or the masks together)
⊡⊚             # ‎⁢⁢select values from input according to mask
```